# Show and hide element in javascript every one second

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to hide and saw some elements in html every one second. I have this code in JavaScript. the hello() is called onload from the main html. and then it starts the timer with the function go called! that it has as I suppose that every one seconds change what it is displayed.

```
function hello() {

myTimer();


}
var indexx = 0;
function myTimer(){
var myVar1=setInterval(function(){go1()},1000);
}
function go1()
{

 if(indexx==0)
    {
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_5");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_1");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");

        indexx+=1;

    }   else
    if(indexx==1)
    {
        results = document.getElementById("water_2_1");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        //
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_7");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");


        indexx+=1;

    }
    if(indexx==2)
    {
    results = document.getElementById("water_2_7");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        //
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_6");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");


        indexx+=1;

    }
    if(indexx==3)
    {
    results = document.getElementById("water_2_6");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        //
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_5");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");

                indexx=0;
        }

}
```

but it only show to me, the first and the last part? 
can someone help me how to achive that?

**THE ANSWER IS:**

```
function hello() {

myTimer();


}
var indexx = 0;
function myTimer(){
var myVar1=setInterval(function(){go1()},1000);
}
function go1()
{

 if(indexx==0)
    {
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_5");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_1");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");

        indexx+=1;

    }   else
    if(indexx==1)
    {
        results = document.getElementById("water_2_1");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        //
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_7");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");


        indexx+=1;

    } else
    if(indexx==2)
    {
    results = document.getElementById("water_2_7");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        //
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_6");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");


        indexx+=1;

    }else 

    {
    results = document.getElementById("water_2_6");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
        //
        var results = document.getElementById("water_2_5");
        results.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");

                indexx=0;
        }

}
```

Comment: You need to use `else if` statements, not just `if`

Comment: oh now i noticed that!!! all day programming!

Comment: I think I see one `else if`, but the other `if` statements need it to, so they are grouped together and only one can be satisfied

Comment: Thanks guys. that was the bug!!

Answer (score 3):

Group all your `if` statements by making all of them (after the first) to be `else if`. That way, the increments inside the blocks (`indexx+=1;`) won't cause the next `if` to be true.